# Securing JSON results

Tags: json, security

I have some code out there in a controller. I tag methods with the [Authorize] attribute so anyone not logged in will not be able to call the method to get the JSON results. The concern has been raised that anyone that's now logged in could easily use fiddler and start hitting urls and getting data thats not necessarily theirs. In the following ajax call:

data: JSON.stringify({ID: 12345})

Lets say this portion of the ajax call is passed in to return data for that user. Well anyone knowing someones elses ID can form a url in fiddler and get data, yes?

Honestly, I've never herd anything about securing JSON to prevent this sort of thing. Anyone here know how to handle this?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To answer part of your question more dirtily, any authenticated user could pass in any value there.  The defacto state you should be in is do not trust anything from the user.  You need to verify on the server that the requester is return data that they should have access to.

You have the authentication taken care of, now you need to implement authorization.  You either need to validate that the ID that is supplied is one that the authenticated user should have access to, or only supply data that is associated with the authenticated user (IE, remove the parameter in the request, and base the data that is returned off the authenticated user).

Hope this helps.